# Floating button to open individual app

Tags: applications, overlay

I am looking for a way to do the following thing: I should see a floating button always on the top, which starts/switches to an individual app I configured.

I know there are a lot of fancy apps, but for me is too much clicking. I just want a simple button that starts my app. When the app is open, I still see the button on the top.

I searched now for 2 hours and installed around 20 apps, but all of them do not please my needs.

My background. I am on a bicycle and need to switch between apps easily.

Can someone help?

Comment: You can construct a Tasker scene (needs [Tasker app](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/download.html)) that would have a button or more to quickly switch to a specific app. Set the scene to show as "overlay blocking" in the task that you would use to show the scene. Take a look at some YouTube videos if you want to figure out what a Tasker scene is and what it can do. I think that should stop your hunt for the app you are after.

Comment: Using a sidebar seems to be better and non intrusive https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fossor.panels or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hiruffy.controller or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paavu.drawerapp